# SQL query error can't find column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have written a simple sql as:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `pre` (`word`, `description`, `status`) VALUES (`$word`, `$desc`, `$status`)";
```

and I am getting error

> Error description: Unknown column 'بد' in 'field list'

and for echo of query I see

> INSERT INTO `pre` (`word`, `description`, `status`) VALUES (`بد`, `بدزبان بدگمان`, `active`)

No sure what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Use straight (single) quotes for string literals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use single quotes for string input in your Statement as like:

```
$query = "
INSERT INTO pre (word, description, status) 
VALUES ('$word', '$desc', '$status')
";
```

**Side note:**
Make sure your table columns collation type is `utf-8` because you are using other language (**URDU**) to insert.

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes instead of backticks in the `values` clause for strings:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `pre` (`word`, `description`, `status`) VALUES ('$word', '$desc', '$status')";
```